# Change a value using mouse click with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mouseclick-event

I am trying to create a nice and simple game just for practice with pygame, and I was trying to change a value using mouse click and I can't find out what to do

```
global item

ev = pygame.event.get()
item = 0

while True:
for event in ev:
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
for event in ev:
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        item + 1
        print (item)
```

After this is run, and I click the mouse, the game just freezes and nothing appears in the shell.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: No need for 2 for statements..

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do and what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

A simple script where clicking in the window increments `item` by 1 and prints it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

item = 0

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            item += 1
            print item
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

This example shows the basic layout and flow of a pygame program.

Notice the `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop contains both of the loops in your example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot :)